# Seaborn/Matplotlib palettes?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to use a palette for my barplot on seaborn from `seaborn.light_palette()`, but how do I incorporate this in to my bar chart?

Usually, I just use the `palette` keyword inside of `sns.barplot` and set it to a string such as "Greens". How do I do it when the palette is from `seaborn.light_palette()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `palette` keyword all the same. Just replace the string such as "Greens" with the value returned by `sns.light_palette()`.

If you don't want to write the whole `light_palette()` function call inside the other function call, you can of course assign its return value to an auxiliary variable:

```py
my_colors = sns.light_palette(...)
sns.barplot(..., palette=my_colors)
```